# Variable cyl as atomic vector

Tags: r

My workspace (aka global environment) contains the data frame mtcars that consists of three variables: mpg, cyl and disp (in that order). Which command return the variable cyl as atomic vector?

Comment: … `mtcars$cyl`.

Comment: mtcars$cyl #(5 more to go)

Answer (score 0):

Or with `dyplr`:

```
library(dyplr)
mtcars %>% pull(cyl)
```

This can be handy if you want to add further operations to the extracted vector.